# sortBy is not working in wso2 DAS. Will you please provie how to query through REST API to WS02 DAS table stream

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

`sortBy` is not working in wso2 DAS. Will you please provide how to query through REST API to WS02 DAS table stream.

I tried similar way shown in below URL but no luck.

```
"sortBy":[{"field":"EmpName", "sortType":"ASC"}]
```

https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Retrieving+All+Records+Matching+the+Given+Search+Query+via+REST+API

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. I made sure that the field that i am sorting by is indexed. In the request, if i remove sortBy, it returns data but when I add sortBy back, I get 500 internal error.

Comment: I recently reached out to their support team, what version of DAS do you have? They said it is available on version 3.1.0 and above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works only in DAS 310. DAS 301 does not have the sorting capability

Answer (score 1):

It should work. Make sure the column you're sorting on is [an index column](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Persisting+Data+for+Interactive+Analytics).

Comment: No luck, all columns have enabled 'index column'. getting (500) Internal Server Error.server. If I remove sortBy i can able to make http request from my application without issues.

Comment: i am having the same issue when trying to sort by indexed column.